# Date to Day conversion in Shell (Sun OS)

Tags: shell, sunos

```
cur_date=`date +"%m/%d/%Y"`         (Output    04/01/2016)                                          
cur_day=`date +"%a"`                (Output    Fri)
```

I wanted to create a new issue from the above commands
But I also want

cur_day =cur_date + "X"

I need someone to help me with "X".

Comment: it is not clear what you mean. Could you elaborate?

Comment: By "SunOS," do you literally mean SunOS 1-4, or are you talking about some version of Solaris, a.k.a. SunOS 5? Be specific.

Comment: Hi Fedorqui & Warren , I have edited the Question ... Let me know if I am still not clear

Comment: If you don't know what version you're running, type `uname -sr`.

Comment: Hello Keith , its SunOS 5.10

Answer (score 1):

I would convert the current date to seconds since [the Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), add the number of days I need to offset by times 86,400¹, and then convert that back to a human-readable date.

The Solaris 11 (a.k.a. SunOS 5.11) `date(1)` program can do the first part via `date '+%s'`, and the POSIX shell² can do arithmetic (e.g. `echo $(($(date '+%s') + 3 * 86400))`), but the Solaris version of `date` can't turn that date-in-seconds value back into a human-formatted date.³

If your system has [GNU `date`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html) installed as `gdate` (as Solaris 11 does), you can close that last gap:

```
$ gdate -d @$(($(gdate '+%s') + 3 * 86400)) '+%m/%d/%Y'
```

That gives a human-formatted version of "3 days hence".

Unfortunately, Solaris 10 (a.k.a. SunOS 5.10) doesn't come with the GNU tools preinstalled. If you're not willing to install them, you'll need a different solution.

A method that *does* work on Solaris 10 and newer is to use Perl, which can do the same thing in a one-liner:

```
$ perl -MPOSIX -e 'print strftime("%m/%d/%Y", localtime(time + 3 * 86400)), "\n"'
```

That might work as far back as Solaris 9.⁴

If you need date manipulation more complicated than that, I recommend using the Perl [`Date::Manip`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Date%3a%3aManip) module. It is quite powerful. It's hunting butterflies with a sledgehammer, but here's how you'd do the above things with `Date::Manip` in a Perl one-liner:

```
$ perl -MDate::Manip -e 'print UnixDate(DateCalc("now", "3d"), "%m/%d/%Y\n")'
```

---

**Footnotes**

1. 86,400 is the number of seconds in a normal day. You might think that the above solutions that use that constant don't work correctly in the face of [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second), but because you are asking for an accuracy in days, it *probably* doesn't matter.

   It only matters if your script is running at the exact second of the leap second adjustment, which normally happens at midnight UTC+0. Here in North America, that's generally after business hours. Some sites move leap second adjustments to a more convenient time, such as 2am local. If your script isn't running at that exact instant, leap seconds can't affect it.

   These adjustments occur only once every few years, and the time of the adjustment is announced months in advance, so you can plan for it if your script absolutely must run at that time and its answer must include the leap second adjustment.
2. All versions of Solaris include a POSIX shell, since POSIX predates Solaris 1.0.
3. This is true through Solaris 11, at least, since it hews pretty closely to the [POSIX `date(1)` spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html).
4. I don't have a Solaris 9 box here to test, so I'm relying on informed speculation: first, that Solaris 9 came with Perl as Solaris 10 and 11 do, and second, that it is Perl 5, so it will accept the [the `-MPOSIX` flag](https://metacpan.org/pod/POSIX) in the solution. Perl 4 didn't support modules, so it didn't have the `-M` flag. I'm sure I could write a different solution that would work with Perl 4, but since you don't need it to work that far back, and it's been 2 decades since I wrote any Perl 4...

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
timestamp="$(date +'%m/%d/%Y') $(date +'%a')"
```

that will be equivalent to:

```
timestamp="04/01/2016 Fri"
```

Comment: Thanks on that , But I am looking for an answer of X                                                             dateday=cur_date +/- "X" = cur_day

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you mean by +/-. Can you rephrase your question in words? As in "I want to calculate the day of week from a date"; or "I want to compute the next day from a date".

Comment: its actually simple calculation terms that I used ... like 10+/-0=10 .. Its not the actual code ... I thought it would be easy to understand ...

Comment: He's asking for date arithmetic here, not string concatenation.

Comment: Thats right warren , I am looking for a equation kind of query which again give me the same answer ...